# How can I automatically create an approve/reject history when I approve a request or return item?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

My process for this is for them to request an item through the project request view and is stored in the Activity model, if a request has been posted they can either approve or reject it using the request approve or request reject view. Now, I want to create a history table that automatically stores the approved or rejected status of a requested item after they approve/reject it, who approved/rejected it, when it was done.

***Models.py***

```
class Activity(models.Model):

Item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, limit_choices_to={'Quantity__gt': 0})
staff = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, limit_choices_to={'Quantity__gt': 0})
project_site = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
Quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=1,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(100),
        MinValueValidator(1)
    ])
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
request_status = models.IntegerField(default=0,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(3)
    ])
return_status = models.IntegerField(default=0,
    validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(3)
    ])
note = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)


class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Item Request'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.Item}'
```

***Views.py***

```
def project_request(request):

activities = Activity.objects.all()
returns = ReturnItem.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ActivityForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.staff = request.user
        instance.request_status = 2
        instance.return_status = 2
        instance.save() 
        return redirect('project_request')

else:
    form = ActivityForm()
context={

    'activities' : activities,
    'returns' : returns,
    'form' : form,
    
}

template_name ='project-admin/project-request-items.html'
return render(request, template_name, context)

def request_approve(request, pk):
activities = Activity.objects.get(id=pk)
activities.request_status = 1
activities.save()
return redirect('project_request')

def request_reject(request, pk):
activities = Activity.objects.get(id=pk)
activities.request_status = 0
activities.save()
return redirect('project_request')
```

Comment: An easy approach will be to create a new history model and update it every time inside request_approve or request_reject method.

Comment: How can I do that without manually adding it to that history model?

Comment: To do it automatically, you will need to use [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/). I have never used them so I'm not familiar with how exactly they work, but the documentation would be a good start.